# How to extract values from a matrix which meet certain characteristics

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, correlation

I have the following [correlation matrix](http://es.tinypic.com/r/zthybs/8):

```
         1            2                 3               4         5            6
1   1.0000000   0.02108494  3.252095e-02    0.09734299  0.13358019  0.2405974
2   -0.4000000  1.00000000  3.844997e-08    0.03570393  0.05800796  0.1398141
3   -0.3730019  0.79262909  1.000000e+00    0.31386596  0.43753022  0.1695814
4   -0.2935198  -0.36689969 -1.808432e-01   1.00000000  0.05911566  0.2826286
5   -0.2666667  -0.33333333 -1.398757e-01   0.33195686  1.00000000  0.3298056
6   -0.2100903  -0.26261287 -2.448878e-01   -0.19270516 -0.17507524 1.0000000
```

where below the diagonal are the correlation index and above the diagonal are the p-values. So I want to extract the pair of datas which have a p-value < 0.05 but a correlation index > 0.5. I was trying something like this:

```
for (i in 1: 6){
for (j in i:6){
if( cor[i,j]<0.05 && cor[i,j]>0){
   correlacion1<-cbind(corx1[i,j]) }} }
```

Just to extract the values which where with p-values<0.05 but It didn't work either. It´s hard to specify different features for over an below the diagonal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be better if you actually posted the data and not an image

you'd want to use `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` to turn those into a vector. than you can loop around those to create a binary vector that captures the conditions you want. Then you can turn that vector into a matrix by `vec2sm()`

```
pVals = correlation[upper.tri(correlation)]
cors =  correlation[lower.tri(correlation)]
selected = vector(length=length(pVals))
selected[pVals<0.5 & cors>0]= TRUE
selectedMatrix = sm2vec(selected)
```

in the end you'll get a symmetric binary matrix. You can turn that into a list of interactions with `graph.adjacency` from `igraph` package if you want. You need to use `get.edgelist` to get the actual list of pairs

Comment: but, is there a way to the vector contains only those datas wich meet those features and the pair of datas? ´cause I'm trying to use this with a matrix with 1200x1500

Comment: how is your desired output shaped like, If you like a list of pairs that meet the criteria, `graph.adjacency` will do it for you

Comment: I'm looking for an output like a list with those pairs, not a graphic way, thanks for your help!

Comment: oh yeah I forgot you had to use `get.edgelist` to the output of `graph.adjacency`